# In cypress, how do I clear the appcache before a test run?

Tags: cypress

Cypress maintains a dedicated user profile, under which there is a persistent appcache (persistent when the cypress browser window is closed). Like chrome, I can clear this manually by going into parameters => clear browsing data. **Can I clear it programmatically ?**